# How to know which div should be scrolled?

Tags: javascript

In a web page, there are two scrollable divs.
When I press `Arrow down key`, one of these divs scrolls down.
How does the webpage know which div should be scrolled?
Is there a mark in this div which should be scrolled?
How to program to verify this?
In fact, I want to control this scroll behavior. When I press Arrow keys, I want to focus in the next item in the div instead of scrolling.

Comment: give us some code you have tried until now

Comment: the div you clicked

Comment: @MVCNoob I know it's the div I clicked. But I want to use code to tell me the differences between these two divs.

Comment: You need to track which div is allready clicked. Its easy...

Comment: you dont use javascript for this, you use css

Comment: Not at all @MVCNoob , you can easily do that in Javascript too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers won't work if you don't set tabindex on divs.

Check here https://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/qb2hy8Lt/

Set tabindex on divs

```
<div id="one" tabindex="1">
```

Capture keydown and prevent the scroll

```
$('div').keydown(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
```

and then handle the keypress

Comment: Why do I have to set tabindex on divs？ Where can I find the official documents about this?

Comment: By default, divs can't have focus on them (you can notice it by clicking on them, they won't have a blue outline). To make they focus-able the tabindex property is used (notice in the fiddle how they get a blue outline when you click over them). You can find some more infos here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute

Comment: And another document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets

Answer (score 0):

if you really wanna use javascript you can try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(eventObject) {
 // do stuff! You can find out about how far the window has scrolled via the eventObject.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give IDs to two divs say div1  and div2

Capture key event of div1 and set focus to div2 inside 
the handler

In case of JQuery you can use following code:-

```
    $('#div1').keydown(function(e) {

       switch(true) {
           case (e.which==37) || (e.which==38) || (e.which==39) ||(e.which==40) : 
           $('#div2').focus();
           break;
           default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
       }

       e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
   });
```

Please let me know in case of any query.

Comment: Keydown event won't work on divs if you don't set the tabindex property